# Knockout: how to make one observable affect another?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I'm using knockout 2.2.1 and I have a page that displays data in tabular manner (using divs not tables) and it has three cols. the left column has a 'Show More' link that when clicking it the middle column should expand.

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" data-title="Search" role="main" id="caspSearch" >
        <header>
            <h2 >Search Results:</h2>
            <span>mobilty fy13</span>
            <p>(<span>25</span>)</p> 
        </header>

        <div class="caspGrid cafeClear">
            <div class="caspRow">
                    <div class="caspColEntity">
                        <span>Favorites</span>
                        <p>(<span>2</span>)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColSummary">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColTeam">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!-- .caspRow -->

                <div class="caspRow">
                    <div class="caspColEntity">
                        <span>Strategies</span>
                        <p>(<span>5</span>)</p>
                      <!-- WHEN CLICKING THIS I WANT THE DIV WITH VISIBLE BINDING (in .caspColSummary) TO SHOW, BUT IT IS ALSO SHOWING THE ONE FROM THE LAST ROW SINCE IT HAS THE SAME BINDING-->
                        <h3 class="caspCollapsible caspRight" data-bind="click:$root.setVisible">Show More</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColSummary">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>

                        <div data-bind="visible:$root.visible">
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColTeam">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>

                        <div data-bind="visible:$root.visible">
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!-- .caspRow -->
                            <div class="caspRow">
                    <div class="caspColEntity">
                        <span>Strategies</span>
                        <p>(<span>5</span>)</p>
                        <h3 class="caspCollapsible caspRight" data-bind="click:$root.setVisible">Show More</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColSummary">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>

                        <div data-bind="visible:$root.visible">
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="caspColTeam">
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>
                        <p>Test Data</p>

                        <div data-bind="visible:$root.visible">
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                            <p>Test Data</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <!-- .caspRow -->

        </div>

</div>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
define(['ko', 'kopost', 'ca', 'sp/db'], function(ko, kopost, ca, db) {

    function SearchViewModel(ctx, data) {
        this.init(ctx, data);
    }

    SearchViewModel.prototype = new ca.ViewModel({});
    SearchViewModel.prototype.constructor = SearchViewModel;

    ko.utils.extend(SearchViewModel.prototype, (function() {

        var init = function(ctx, data){
            var self = this;    
            self.visible = ko.observable(false);    
            self.results = ko.observableArray();
            self.subscribeToTopic("caspSearch", self.search, self); 
        },


        setVisible = function(o,e){
            this.visible(!this.visible());
            $(e.target).toggleClass('caspOpen');
        };


        return {
                init: init,                 
                setVisible:setVisible

        }
    })());

    return SearchViewModel;
});
```

Obviously setting the visible this way is problematic since it is showing all the columns with the visible binding, how can i make it flexible so it will only show the column i need?

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to "Show more" for a *single* item at any one time then you need to track the currently selected item within your view model. You can then use this to evaluate whether the "Show more" column should be displayed for each item.

A simplified example.

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: contacts">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.selectContact">More</a>
        <div data-bind="visible: $parent.isSelected($data)"><span data-bind="text: age"></span></div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var contacts = [{
    name: "John",
    age: 30
}, {
    name: "Pete",
    age: 25
}, {
    name: "Jane",
    age: 23
}];

var ContactsModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.selectedContact = ko.observable();

    self.isSelected = function (item) {
        return self.selectedContact() && self.selectedContact() === item;
    };

    self.selectContact = function (item) {
        self.selectedContact(item);
    };
};

var model = new ContactsModel(contacts);
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

The key things to note:

- Clicking the "More" link for an item sets the `selectedContact` property of the view model. The handler for the click event is passed the *current* item.
- The "More" div has a visible binding set to the `isSelected` function on the parent view model. In this case we need to explicitly pass the current item using the special `$data` variable.

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/fPhZQ/

Another option is to have an `isSelected` observable for each contact but my preference is the solution above.